# How to rewrite the url from www.example.com/index.php?store=test to test.example.com or www.test.example.com in .htacess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite the url from **www.example.com/index.php?store=test** to **test.example.com** or **www.test.example.com**

can any body suggest me how to implement the rewrite code in .htaccess file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to /root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
#--Redirect from "www.example.com/index.php?store=test"--#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?store=test [NC]
#--to "store.example.com"--#
RewriteRule ^ http://store.example.com [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi above code is not worked for me. This is my website http://kartdemo.tk/index.php?store=test

Comment: it is redirection to http://store.kartdemo.tk/?store=test but not displaying any thing just showing error page index.php just printing the store parameter value. it is all ways redirecting to store.kartdemo.tk but i want not like that when store parameter is test url becomes test.kartdemo.tk when store value test1 now url becomes test1.kartdemo.tk  how to rewrite this dynamically  please help me.